# How to calculate loop delay in avr based architectures

Tags: avr, timing

I am trying to do some high time precision work (well not that high, but more than normal) and would need calculate the time delay generated by a small loop. Can anyone help me with that? These are just generic instructions like these

```
for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
{
if(i<x)

    PORTA |= (1<<0);
else
    PORTA &= ~(1<<0);
if(i<y)
    PORTA |= (1<<1);
else
    PORTA &= ~(1<<1);
if(i<z)
        PORTA |= (1<<2);
else
    PORTA &= ~(1<<2);
```

}

This is just an example.

The controller is an ATmega32 working on the internal 8MHz RC oscillator.

Comment: The only way to achieve high precision is to use assembly. Your C compiler may optimise in non-obvious ways

Comment: An example of using assembly for precision delays is included in the avr-libc util/delay.h file which may be a good starting point.

Comment: Heres an [excellent tutorial](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=50106) and no its not written by me another Dean but is written very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your loop toggle an IO line and measure the frequency of the resulting signal, either with an oscilloscope, or a multimeter with a frequency setting.

Answer (score 4):

The AVR Studio simulator will tell you how many clock cycles that loop takes for the various conditions, if you set them up properly.

Comment: I think this the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can benchmark the timings using one of the 16 bit timers such as timer1 or timer3.
Don't forget to time the timing harness as well and correct for it!